# ReactJs: How to prevent form submission when clicked on a terms of service link?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a `React` project with a `bootstrap` form with a checkbox for "I agree to Terms of Service". When clicked on "Terms of Service", it opens a modal with Terms of Service as content. Every thing works fine *except when I close the modal*, *it also submit the form*. **I do not want the form to submit when I close the form**. I want the user to submit the form by clicking the submit button instead. **How do I achieve this?**

```
...

<form>
...
 <div className="form-check">
  <input
   className="form-check-input"
   type="checkbox"
   checked={state.agree}
   name='agree'
   id="agreeCheck"
   onChange={(e) => setState((state) => ({ ...state, agree: !state.agree}))}
 />
  <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>I agree to Terms of Service</a>
  <Modal show={show} closeModal={closeModal} title={""}>{<TermsOfService/>}</Modal>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" disabled={!state.agree}/>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't put the modal inside the form.

Comment: You are right!!! thank you it worked. Didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code... credit goes to #GuyIncognito

```
...

<form>
...
 <div className="form-check">
  <input
   className="form-check-input"
   type="checkbox"
   checked={state.agree}
   name='agree'
   id="agreeCheck"
   onChange={(e) => setState((state) => ({ ...state, agree: !state.agree}))}
 />
  <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>I agree to Terms of Service</a>

 </div>
 <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" disabled={!state.agree}/>
</form>
  <Modal show={show} closeModal={closeModal} title={""}>{<TermsOfService/>}</Modal>
...
```